# Anaconda: "kraken" is not running in my virtual environment despite being installed there

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, ocr, conda

I'm using a fresh install of Kubuntu 19.04. I'm also very new to Python and anaconda, so it's possible the mistake I am making is quite obvious. I am trying to run the OCR program [kraken](http://kraken.re/) in a virtual environment created through conda, yet when I run any kraken commands (`kraken list` `kraken get 10.5281/zenodo.2577813`), I get the following error:

```
Command 'kraken' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install kraken
```

I created the virtual environment using the instructions found [here](http://kraken.re/#conda):

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mittagessen/kraken/master/environment.yml
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

I then entered the kraken environment through `conda activate kraken`, but found that `kraken list` did not work. I attempted to reinstall kraken through `conda install --name kraken kraken`. When I use `conda list`, kraken is listed as an installed package.

I thought the problem might be due to an error in my .bashrc. In my .bashrc, conda had created:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/USERNAME/Programming/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/USERNAME/Programming/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/USERNAME/Programming/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/USERNAME/Programming/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
#unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

After the error, I commented out the above and changed it to:

```
. /home/USERNAME/Programming/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate
```

That did not fix the problem. Both are at the bottom of my .bashrc. I have not tried moving them to the top.

Again, after each change I attempted `kraken list` but rather than getting a list of available models, I instead got:

```
Command 'kraken' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install kraken
```

Is there another command I am supposed to use to use python programs in conda created environments?

Aditionally: The kraken program that I can install from the Ubuntu repository seems to be a program to categorize DNA, not an OCR program.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Issue](https://github.com/mittagessen/kraken/issues/143#issuecomment-515438419), explains it/sums it up. You have to install **kraken** from the `github master` branch, and not using **conda envs**.

Simply:

```
# Clone the master branch into kraken directory.
$ git clone https://github.com/mittagessen/kraken.git

# And then, Use a virtualenv or just:

$ pip3 install .
```

This completes the installation of **kraken**, you can verify it using :

```
$ kraken list
$ Retrieving model list .✓
10.5281/zenodo.2577813 (pytorch) - A generalized model for English printed text
```